# Dump Mysql Table with character "@" in their name

Tags: mysql, command-line-interface

It seems i cannot dump my table (with "@" character) using this command

```
sudo mysqldump -u root -p --single-transaction --routines --triggers -h 127.0.0.1 my_db "tbl_field_values_259778_hut@002b1" > tbl_field_values_259778_hut@002b1.sql
```

When i execute command, It shows :

```
mysqldump: Couldn't find table: "tbl_field_values_259778_hut@002b1"
```

Unfortunately i dont have permission to rename the table inside mysql command line.

This command is not work either (using escape and quotes)

```
sudo mysqldump -u root -p --single-transaction --routines --triggers -h 127.0.0.1 my_db "tbl_field_values_259778_hut\@002b1" > tbl_field_values_259778_hut\@002b1.sql
sudo mysqldump -u root -p --single-transaction --routines --triggers -h 127.0.0.1 my_db "tbl_field_values_259778_hut\@002b1" > "tbl_field_values_259778_hut\@002b1.sql"
```

Comment: I tried it with MySQL 5.6.31, and it works fine. I suggest the table does not have the name you think it does, or else it's not in the database `my_db`. Try `mysql -u root -p -h 127.0.0.1 my_db -e "show tables"`

Comment: thank you, i found the culprit

    $ mysql -u root -p mobisys_smsb_group_reminder_db -e "show tables" | grep 259778

    tbl_field_values_259778_hut+1

Comment: Okay, I have voted to close this question as: can not be reproduced / typographical error.